# How can i call JNIEXPORT function from dll in other c++ dll

Tags: c++, dll, java-native-interface

I write visual c++ dll with one JNIEXPORT function as below:

```
extern "C"
{
    JNIEXPORT int JNICALL sum()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I want call this function in other visual c++ dll as below:

```
typedef int(__stdcall *f_funci)();

HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary("C:/.../JNIdllTest.dll");

if (!hGetProcIDDLL) {

    std::cout << "could not load the dynamic library" << std::endl;

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

    f_funci funci = (f_funci)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "sum");

if (!funci) {

    std::cout << "could not locate the function" << std::endl;

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

std::cout << "funci() returned " << funci() << std::endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

but when i run it this error occur

> could not locate the function

what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your "sum" function is not really dll-exported from the JNIdllTest.dll. You can see the functions exported from a DLL by e.g. opening the DLL in dependency walker: http://www.dependencywalker.com/.

So download that and check if the exports view has the sum function or not, and whether the name of the function is just plain "sum" or whether it is decorated somehow. (C++ by default adds to the function name the types of the return value and function parameters).

It should not be decorated as your function is inside an extern "C" block, but if it is, make sure that the function declaration also has extern "C" in front of it.

If the function is really not exported from the DLL, then check what your definition of JNIEXPORT is, and try using "__declspec(dllexport)" instead - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sami Sallinen

> So download that and check if the exports view has the sum function or not, and whether the name of the function is just plain "sum" or whether it is decorated somehow. (C++ by default adds to the function name the types of the return value and function parameters).

[image]